# How to use `\polymerdelim`

Tags: chemfig

```
\chemfig{N-[1]N-[7]N}\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 45pt, depth = 40pt, indice = n]{op}{cl}
```

May I know why it is not working? I am new to chemfig.
(Also I know that this is not a real polymer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second and third argument of `\polymerdelim`, here `{op}` and `{cl}`, are node names. You need to specify in the `\chemfig` declaration where these nodes are, with the syntax `@{somename}`.

This name declaration goes inside of the optional argument, directly before any other arguments (without a delimiter such as comma), for example `[1]` becomes `[@{op}1]`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{N-[@{op}1]N-[@{cl}7]N}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 25pt, depth = 20pt, indice = n]{op}{cl} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

More examples can be found in the [chemfig manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), section 12.4
*Draw a polymer element*.